# Submit by pressing enter in a windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

In order to transfer text from one textbox to another, I have created a submit button. However it would be preferable to use the functionality of the 'enter' key.

I am not sure but i think the ascii code is 13.Anyway how do I go about this task at hand?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at the `Form.AcceptButton` property.

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to the KeyUp event of the text box.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

private void txtInput_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: My upvote was not because it was related to this specific question but because I found this while looking for solutions to my specific problem and it worked. I wanted to submit a form when the user added text to a combo box and pressed Enter.